# Indexing Lists of Strings

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

In Python, I have a list of strings that repeat the same string every 7th element:

```
test_list = ['1315', '1415', '1515', '1615', '1715', '1815','1915', '1315','1415', '1515', and so on].
```

I want to be able to only print out the indexes of one particular element such as all of the '1415' variables. I have been able to do this for the `'1315'` one by doing `test_list[::7]`, which will return all of the `'1315'` in the list. I now want to do this for every other string in the list.

Comment: Why not `test_list[1::7]`, etc.?

Comment: So in short, the entire list repeats every 7 items? Then a bit of math will already give you the answer... starting index * 7 repeated `len(test_list) / 7` times... That would also obviate the need to keep the entire redundant list around...

Comment: That worked, thank you! I was doing test_list[1:7], which now makes sense as to why it was only giving me the first six values of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
indices = [idx for (idx, element) in enumerate(test_list) if element == "1315"]
```

Comment: this will only works if he/she already knows what element they were looking for this may not always be the case

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index('bar')
1
```

With this istruction you can have the position of the element.
This is the python reference of [Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: But only the *first* index